# php foreach goes into infinite loop, array stored in session

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, infinite-loop, array-splice

All works perfectly, but when there are more one items in the cart.. and the the quantity of any item (except the last item in list) is changed the code below goes into infinite loop, i have verified it by placing print_r statements in it.

The part of the code that goes into infinite loop:

```
if (isset($_POST['item_to_adjust']) && $_POST['item_to_adjust'] != "") {
    // execute some code
    $item_to_adjust = $_POST['item_to_adjust'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $quantity = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $quantity); // filter everything but numbers
    if ($quantity >= 100) { $quantity = 99; }
    if ($quantity < 1) { $quantity = 1; }
    if ($quantity == "") { $quantity = 1; }
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
              print_r($each_item);
              $i++;
              while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                  if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $item_to_adjust) {
                      // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                      array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $item_to_adjust, "quantity" => $quantity)));
                  } // close if condition
              } // close while loop
    } // close foreach loop
}
```

P.S.

This is how the array is initialized when 1st item is added.

```
$_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
```

If any other detail is required please let me know..

Update : Suppose there are three items in in a cart. And i change the quantity of the 3rd item. It work.
But if i change the quantity of the 2nd item, The script hits max execution time and  the 2nd and 3rd items are repeated in the cart infinitely.

Comment: Making changes to an array you're looping over is a VERY BAD idea!

Comment: I had a feeling it might affect the for loop if i add/remove items.. But am just replacing the item inside the loop.. thought it should not pose as a problem.

Comment: You are adding the items to the array before the loop reaches the end.

Comment: @PrathameshGharat Replacing an array element will lead to the array being reindexed.  What effect that will have on looping constructs is anyone's guess.

Comment: thanks GordonM Thanks for the detailed explanation.
Makes sense now, doing array_splice after the for loop would have had worked i guess but accessing the array directly is much better, thanks too fragmentedreality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $item_key => $each_item) {
    if ($item_to_adjust == $each_item["item_id"]) {
        $_SESSION["cart_array"][$item_key]["quantity"] = $quantity;
    }
}
```

This is still modifying the array inside the loop (not cool), but it does not mess with indexes.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it.
But i tried the original code here.. http://tinyurl.com/c5qh3ha 
and it does work as expected..