# PHP endless looping

Tags: php, html, session, loops

I have a piece of code which causes an endless loop but only in certain circumstances.

It's for a shopping cart quantity change and at the moment the cart works correctly when changing the quantity of the last item added. but for example if I have 3 items in the cart i can not change the quantity of the 1st or 2nd item because the loops runs endlessly.

Im not sure what is wrong with this code Ive found similar problems but no solution.

The code looks like this:

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $each_item) { 
          $i++;
          while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
              if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $item_to_adjust) {
                  // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                  array_splice($_SESSION["cart"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $item_to_adjust, "quantity" => $quantity)));
              } // close if condition
          } // close while loop
                if ($i > 50) die("manual termination");
} // close foreach loop
```

If i do a var_dump on the SESSION when i have added 2 items to the cart it displays the following:

**array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["item_id"]=> string(11) "100-C09EJ01" ["quantity"]=> string(1) "3" } [1]=> array(2) { ["item_id"]=> string(11) "700-CF220EJ" ["quantity"]=> int(1) } }**

Could someone help me please?

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: what is in `$_SESSION["cart"]`?

Comment: Could you add a var_dump of `$_SESSION` to your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php foreach goes into infinite loop, array stored in session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222987/php-foreach-goes-into-infinite-loop-array-stored-in-session)

Comment: You use `$_SESSION["cart"]` in `foreach($_SESSION["cart"]...)` and than you change element in `$_SESSION["cart"]`  `array_splice($_SESSION["cart"]...)` !!! Don't do this !!!

Comment: @andrewsi ok I have included that into the question. (furas)...Thanks for the heads up but I got this code from a tutorial online and I dont know any alternative way to do it

Comment: Maybe try Justin answer.

Comment: yeah thank you furas I did that :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're modifying an array while you're looping over it. An extremely simple solution is to modify a copy of the array and then replace the original after the loop is finished.

```
$newcart = $_SESSION["cart"];
foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $each_item) { 
  $i++;
  while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
    if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $item_to_adjust) {
      array_splice($newcart, $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $item_to_adjust, "quantity" => $quantity)));
    }
  }
  if ($i > 50) die("manual termination");
}
$_SESSION["cart"] = $newcart;
```

Comment: Thankyou Justin!! that has fixed it :-) and I have been stuck on that for hours...thankyou very much

Comment: This `$newcart = $_SESSION["cart"];` creates a copy